# Stop a particular OSX application icon jumping

Tags: macos

My Outlook 2011 icon starts jumps every half hour or so because one account or other has failed to connect.  There is no real problem as the account normally resolves itself, but Outlook's jumping icon is difficult to ignore.  I don't want to deactivate all icon jumping behaviour - all other posts I've read show how to do this in terminal.  I just want to stop Outlook.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Outlook has no such setting, so I'm looking for a bash solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Outlook –> Preferences… Notifications & Sounds > Bounce Outlook Icon in Dock
```

[image: Outlook Notifications]

Comment: Thanks, but that's for new messages. My issue is when Outlook gives notifications about account connection errors. My message bounce setting is unticked but the icon still bounces all the time..

Comment: You would likely have to dump the strings from the outlook application binary to see if theres a hidden preference for the setting.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: In terminal paste: `strings - /Applications/<path to outlook.app>/Contents/MacOS/Outlook > ~/desktop/outlook_strings` (you need to find the exact path of `Outlook.app`). Then search the file on your desktop (outlook_strings) for `bounce`, or `error`perhaps.